# Xcode can't see a certificate I downloaded and added to my keychain access

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I'm currently trying to validate my project. Every time I try, I get a message reading "Xcode failed to locate or generate matching signing assets and failed to do so because of the following reasons: Your Account already has a valid iOS Distribution Certificate." (I'm part of a Development Team — with several preexisting distribution and development certificates — and have downloaded a distribution certificate and added it to my keychain access.) Why can't Xcode see the distribution certificate I already downloaded?

Comment: Did you press Refresh button in Xcode menu > Preferences > Accounts > Choose your team > Details ? Also, no such thing called X-Code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all provisioning profiles from within your apple dev center account and archive your project again. When the dialog appears, where Xcode tries to recognize your provisioning profiles within your apple dev account it will recreate the necessary profiles for you. I had the same problem und this was the only solution.
Since Xcode 6 it will (better "tries to") manage your provisioning profiles and certificates for you in the apple developer center. Sometimes Xcode are not able to migrate existing provisioning profiles to the new managed solution.